# How can I filter out duplicate ids in a loop from list

Tags: python, list, filter, lambda

I have such a list at hand. In this list, I want to filter the `deposits` under each `witdrawal` by removing the same ones from another list. This cluster is currently clustered over 2 `withdrawals`, but this may vary. Therefore, as much as a `withdrawal` cluster in one cycle, the `deposit` in one `withdrawal` should not be in another `withdrawal` cluster. For this, I tried various lambda functions over `deposit` `id`, but I could not get the desired output. How can I provide this?

```
exampleList = [
    {
      "withdrawal": {
        "amount": 250,
        "id": 70916631583,
        "date": "31-05-22 - 16:14:08",
        "paytype": "withdrawal"
      },
      "deposit": [
        {
          "id": 71018974368,
          "amount": 120,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 14:27:26",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        },
        {
          "id": 71018971332,
          "amount": 100,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 14:27:23",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "withdrawal": {
        "amount": 220,
        "id": 71019072820,
        "date": "01-06-22 - 14:28:40",
        "paytype": "withdrawal"
      },
      "deposit": [
        {
          "id": 71033338591,
          "amount": 100,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 17:03:19",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        },
        {
          "id": 71033144597,
          "amount": 250,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 17:01:20",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        },
        {
          "id": 71018974368,
          "amount": 120,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 14:27:26",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        },
        {
          "id": 71018971332,
          "amount": 100,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 14:27:23",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Example Output:

```
exampleOutputList = [
    {
      "withdrawal": {
        "amount": 250,
        "id": 70916631583,
        "date": "31-05-22 - 16:14:08",
        "paytype": "withdrawal"
      },
      "deposit": [
        {
          "id": 71018974368,
          "amount": 120,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 14:27:26",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        },
        {
          "id": 71018971332,
          "amount": 100,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 14:27:23",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "withdrawal": {
        "amount": 220,
        "id": 71019072820,
        "date": "01-06-22 - 14:28:40",
        "paytype": "withdrawal"
      },
      "deposit": [
        {
          "id": 71033338591,
          "amount": 100,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 17:03:19",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        },
        {
          "id": 71033144597,
          "amount": 250,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 17:01:20",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        }
        
      ]
    }
  ]
```

The deposits with id `71018974368` and `71018971332` that I show in the sample printout are not available in the next one as they were in the previous withdrawal cluster. This is exactly what I wanted to do. This withdrawal clustering can be more than 2, so it can vary, so doing this by indexing the elements will not solve my problem.

I tried something like this. I waited for it to resend the ids into an empty list and filter through the loop, but the output I got did not change.

```
listLen = len(exampleList)
testList = []
if(listLen > 0):
    while listLen > 0:
        listLen -= 1
        deposits = exampleList[listLen]['deposit']
        withDrawal = exampleList[listLen]['withdrawal']
        idList = [x['id'] for x in deposits]
        filterFromList = list(filter(lambda x:x['id'] not in testList, deposits))
        testList.append({"withdrawal" : withDrawal,"deposit" : filterFromList})
        
    print(testList)
```

Output

```
[{'withdrawal': {'amount': 220, 'id': 71019072820, 'date': '01-06-22 - 14:28:40', 'paytype': 'withdrawal'}, 'deposit': [{'id': 71033338591, 'amount': 100, 'date': '01-06-22 - 17:03:19', 'paytype': 'deposit'}, {'id': 71033144597, 'amount': 250, 'date': '01-06-22 - 17:01:20', 'paytype': 'deposit'}, {'id': 71018974368, 'amount': 120, 'date': '01-06-22 - 14:27:26', 'paytype': 'deposit'}, {'id': 71018971332, 'amount': 100, 'date': '01-06-22 - 14:27:23', 'paytype': 'deposit'}]}, {'withdrawal': {'amount': 250, 'id': 70916631583, 'date': '31-05-22 - 16:14:08', 'paytype': 'withdrawal'}, 'deposit': [{'id': 71018974368, 'amount': 120, 'date': '01-06-22 - 14:27:26', 'paytype': 'deposit'}, {'id': 71018971332, 'amount': 100, 'date': '01-06-22 - 14:27:23', 'paytype': 'deposit'}]}]
```

There are repetitive deposit ids and elements as seen in the output.

Comment: what have you tried so far? add that code please

Comment: I tried many things for this. As an example, I wanted to distinguish it from the others with the lambda function by taking the elements in a for loop. I also made tests with the while loop, so I didn't share it because I thought that writing the tests I made here might create confusion in terms of understanding the problem.

Comment: The problem is not understanding the problem. The problem is helping you solve the problem via code. I can just write a solution for you, but it is better if you provide code that can be moved in the right direction. Have you solved "any" part of the problem at all yet?

Comment: perhaps the solution requires more then a one-liner. I.e. some actual methods

Comment: I shared only 1 of the ones I tried, you can check it.

Comment: much better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a set of already-seen ids as you traverse the data. For each cluster, keep a side list of ids not seen and replace the the "deposit" list before advancing to the next cluster. This is a lot easier than trying to track indexes of the nested collections.

```
seen = set()

for cluster in exampleList:
    filtered = []
    for deposit in cluster["deposit"]:
        if deposit["id"] not in seen:
            seen.add(deposit["id"])
            filtered.append(deposit)
    cluster["deposit"][:] = filtered
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List = [
    {
      "withdrawal": {
        "amount": 250,
        "id": 70916631583,
        "date": "31-05-22 - 16:14:08",
        "paytype": "withdrawal"
      },
      "deposit": [
        {
          "id": 71018974368,
          "amount": 120,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 14:27:26",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        },
        {
          "id": 71018971332,
          "amount": 100,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 14:27:23",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "withdrawal": {
        "amount": 220,
        "id": 71019072820,
        "date": "01-06-22 - 14:28:40",
        "paytype": "withdrawal"
      },
      "deposit": [
        {
          "id": 71033338591,
          "amount": 100,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 17:03:19",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        },
        {
          "id": 71033144597,
          "amount": 250,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 17:01:20",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        },
        {
          "id": 71018974368,
          "amount": 120,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 14:27:26",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        },
        {
          "id": 71018971332,
          "amount": 100,
          "date": "01-06-22 - 14:27:23",
          "paytype": "deposit"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

def func(d):
     if type(d)==list:

          for i in reversed(range(len(d))):
               v=d[i]
       
               if v.get('id')  in (71018974368,
                               71018971332):
                    d.pop(i)
               else:
                    func(v)
     elif type(d)==dict:
          for k,v in d.items():
               func(v)

func(List)
print(List)
```